# Simple card game to learn OOP

Tags: python, object-oriented, game, playing-cards

My goal was to get my hands dirty in OOP by designing and using classes and getting started with inheritance and other OOP concepts.

I have written a very small code to play a card Game called "War". The rules are simple. Each person playing the game is given 1 card. The person with the highest card wins. I am not worrying too much about Ties right now. My code *does* work but I wanted feedback on my OOP usage.

---

```
import itertools
import random
class Cards:
    def __init__(self):
        self.suits = ['Spades','Hearts','Diamonds','Clubs']
        self.values = range(1,14)
        self.ActualCards = [] #Empty List to Append
        for Card in itertools.product(self.suits,self.values):
            self.ActualCards.append(Card) #Cartesian Product to Create Deck
    def GetRandomCard(self):
        RandomNumber = random.randint(0,51)
        CardToBeReturned = self.ActualCards[RandomNumber] #Generates Random Card
    return(CardToBeReturned)

class Player:
    def __init__(self,ID,Card):
        self.PlayerID = ID
        self.CardForPlayer = Card

class Game:
    def __init__(self,NameOfGame):
        self.name = NameOfGame

class SimpleWar(Game):
    def __init__(self,NumberOfPlayers):
        self.NumberOfPlayers = NumberOfPlayers
        self.PlayerList = []
    def StartGame(self):
        DeckOfCards = Cards()
        for playerID in range(0,self.NumberOfPlayers):
            CardForPlayer = DeckOfCards.GetRandomCard() #Deal Card to Player
            NewPlayer = Player(playerID,CardForPlayer) #Save Player ID and Card
            self.PlayerList.append(NewPlayer)
        self.DecideWinner()    
    def DecideWinner(self):
        WinningID = self.PlayerList[0] #Choose Player 0 as Potential Winner
        for playerID in self.PlayerList:
            if(playerID.CardForPlayer[1]>WinningID.CardForPlayer[1]):
                WinningID = playerID #Find the Player with Highest Card
        print "Winner is Player "+str(WinningID.PlayerID)
        print "Her Card was "+ str(WinningID.CardForPlayer[1]) + " of " + str(WinningID.CardForPlayer[0]) 


if __name__=="__main__":
    NewGame = SimpleWar(2)
    NewGame.StartGame()
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Syntax Error

In `Cards.GetRandomCard()`, the `return` statement is incorrectly indented.  (Also, I would recommend writing the `return` without parentheses.)

#### Style Conventions

[Use `lower_case_names` for variables and methods.](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables)

For readability, please add one <kbd>space</kbd> after each comma, and one <kbd>newline</kbd> between functions definitions.

#### Modeling

Your `Game` class isn't useful.  You never set or use `NameOfGame`.  I recommend getting rid of the `Game` class altogether.

In a real-life card game, you would deal a card from the deck to each player, without replacement.  In your code, you deal with replacement (i.e., **there is a chance of dealing the same card to both players**).  A more realistic simulation would do a `random.shuffle()` on the array.  When dealing, you would `pop()` a card from the list to remove it from the deck.  51 is a "magic" number; you should use `len(self.ActualCards) - 1`.

`Cards` is really a `Deck`.  Rather than just a tuple of strings, you should have a `Card` class representing a single card.  The `Card` class should have a `__str__()` method that returns a string such as `"Ace of diamonds"`.  If you also define [comparison operators](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html), then you can determine the winner using `max(self.PlayerList, key=lambda player: player.CardForPlayer)`.

#### Expressiveness

In Python, you can usually avoid creating an empty list and appending to it:

```
self.ActualCards = [] #Empty List to Append
for Card in itertools.product(self.suits,self.values):
    self.ActualCards.append(Card) #Cartesian Product to Create Deck
```

Instead, you should be able to build it all at once:

```
self.actual_cards = list(itertools.product(self.suits, self.values))
```

Comment: [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) suggests *two* newlines between function and class definitions. However, one is better than nothing.

Comment: @nyuszika7h PEP 8 only calls for one blank line between method definitions within a class, which is what matters here.

Comment: @200_success: It would be hard to define a comparison for the `Card`s, as the order only has meaning in the context of a particular game. So it's a `Game` responsibility (War, Solitaire, etc) to compare two cards.

Comment: @200_success You're right, I didn't bother to check if it's within a class.

Answer (score 11):

Cool app. My comments aren't intended to be critical or haughty, just me thinking out loud.

- Python 3? If not, make sure your classes extend `object`.
- I probably wouldn't define and extend `Game`. It doesn't add anything. You don't need to generalize or abstract the idea of a `Game`, especially in this context.
- More broadly, it's a good practice to avoid inheritance. Do a search on "favor composition over inheritance" for more on that.
- The state of `Cards` doesn't change... the point of having a class is managing state. So I'd have something like `pick_card` that actually removes the selected card from the deck. Otherwise you'd probably be better off just using a function—at least in Python. Classes are all about bundling data and functions so you can manage state safely. Absent that, they kind of lose their luster (unless you're writing Java ;) ).
- This is just me, but I wouldn't have `StartGame` run the loop or decide the winner. Again, I'd have `__init__` start the game, and then have something like `run_game`. Again, rely on the class to manage the state. Each method is supposed to move it farther along.
- Knowing me, I'd break out `__init__`, `play_a_turn`, `decide_game`, and `show_game` as methods and loop *outside* the class to keep the calling structure flat.
- IMHO your logic for deciding the winner, and the logic for *displaying* the winner could go in separate methods. I like keeping methods small, light, and targeted.
- Again, I'd make `SimpleWar.__init__` do more, and `StartGame` do less. If I had a `StartGame` at all.

**EDIT:** I like to define my classes closely to the things they model. So instead of `Cards`, I'd probably have Deck, with methods shuffle and pick. I also like the comment above about spinning off a separate method to compare cards—I'd definitely do that.

Comment: It's not Python 3, because it uses Python 2's `print`  syntax.

Comment: ah, good call. I'm still self-conscious about not having migrated. In that case, make sure that your __init__ methods invoke the base class's __init__, either directly or with super()

Comment: For future reference, use \`\_\_init\_\_\` to make it display properly. Or if you want to bold it, `**\_\_init\_\_**`.

Answer (score 11):

From a testing perspective, it would be good, to inject the deck (`Cards`) and the players into the game. Also printing the results in the game object is not a very good idea, I think. Maybe it would be better, to return the round, that contains the winner. This could then also be used for logging or a mastership :)

```
Deck = Deck()
Game = SimpleWar(Deck)
Game.addPlayer(Player('Andrea'))
Game.addPlayer(Player('Bert'))
Round = Game.play()
Winner = Round.get_winner()
print('The winner is: ' + str(Winner))
print('The winning card is: ' + str(Winner.get_last_card()))

Deck.shuffle()
Round = Game.play()
```

As said before, the deck should contain card objects (or an array and build the card objects, when requested, if those card objects would be expensive) and the cards should have to be put back into the deck after each game round (or a `reset()` method of the deck could be called by the game). The question then would be, who remembers the winning card, after all cards have been returned into the deck. In the example above, this is the player (`get_last_card()`), but it could be stored in the `Round`, too.

This way you don't have any object instantiation in your classes, except for the deck, that builds card objects. This would be very good testable. For example, you can pass a deck mock into the game and define, which cards it should return in the single requests to test the detection of the winner.

Search the web for "dependency injection" for more information.

Comment: what I like about your design is that you've thought through the interactions between objects, and that defines their methods. Also big plus for dependency injection.

Answer (score 5):

At a glance, I would recommend putting a `CompareTo(OtherCard)` function in the `Card` class, and using that for `DecideWinner`.

Comment: The value of a card is game dependent. In a world, where those cards could be used for many different games, the cards wouldn't know their own values. So, I think, the `WarGame` object is a good place, to put this decision in.

Comment: @stofl The only thing that would change for numerical comparison is whether aces are high or low, and it actually doesn't matter at all unless aces could be either within the same game, or if cards are passed between games for some reason.

Comment: If the value of a card is an attribute of the card, then a compare method makes sense in the card class. If the value of a card is defined in the game rules, then the card class would be not the right place for a compare method. In the concrete code, we have the value in the cards - in real world we most often don't: Cards have many different values in different games.

Comment: @stofl I think that what's in the code is more relevant than what's in real life; and in the code, there is only one game, and only one definition of card comparison.